# Bash freezes after SSH login unless Ctrl+C is pressed immediately

Tags: bash, ssh, freeze, login

I'm facing an issue where my Ubuntu bash freezes after an SSH login **unless I press Ctrl+C immediately**. It appears that something is loading in the background. This problem started occurring after I received numerous bash messages like:

```
watchpack error (watcher): error: enospc: system limit for number of file watchers reached, watch ....
```

which were triggered when I tried to start an Angular application using IntelliJ Remote Development. How can I resolve this problem and prevent the freezing of my bash after SSH login?

## **UPDATE (Problem is solved):**

I encountered the root cause of the terminal freezing issue in my case. The problem was related to the command `ng completion` used for my Angular application. Surprisingly, this command was automatically appended to my `~/.bashrc` file, leading to the freezing behavior. Here is the specific line that caused the problem:

```
# Load Angular CLI autocompletion.
source <(ng completion script)
```

To resolve the issue, I simply removed the problematic line from the `~/.bashrc` file.

I'm uncertain how this line ended up in my `~/.bashrc` file, but I suspect it might be related to my usage of IntelliJ Remote Development. However, this is just a speculation and requires further investigation.

If you encounter a similar problem, I suggest following these steps to regain terminal functionality:

1. Immediately after entering the SSH credentials, press Ctrl+C multiple times. This will prevent the execution of the problematic line in my `~/.bashrc` file and allow the terminal to become usable in my case.
2. Once the terminal is accessible, check the `~/.bashrc` file for any unexpected or problematic lines, especially those that were recently added. In my case, the line involving `ng completion` was the culprit.
3. Remove or comment out any suspicious lines in the `~/.bashrc` file that could be causing the freezing issue.
4. Save the changes to `~/.bashrc` and restart the terminal or source the file again to apply the modifications.

Alternatively you could also rename temporaly the complete file to check if this is causing the problem: using `cd ~` and then `mv .bashrc newfilename`

By following these steps, I was able to (1.) use my terminal again and (2.) resolve the freezing problem and restore normal functionality to my terminal.

Lesson learned for the future: Always good to have a second user account that can be used for SSH login.

Comment: Move the solution into an **Answer**, just first click "Answer my own question".
`[ ] Answer your own question – share your knowledge, Q&A-style`